# How to pass the result of JQuery Ajax call to the php variable?

Tags: jquery

How can I pass the result of a jQuery AJAX call to the PHP variable? Here, result of thr AJAX call is an array.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url:"test.php",
            success: function(result){
            }
        }) 
    }
</script> 

<?php
    $phpRlt = ?
?>
```

Comment: you cant ... jQuery is browser side and PHP is server size - you can send data to PHP using AJAX (which you are doing) - what are you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no downvote from me .... just trying to help with my comment - i was there once ....

Comment: @ManseUK That's cool, I wasn't specifically targetting you. Downvoting needlessly just seems to be getting more and more common lately.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan agreed - its the first thing that puts people off wanting to ask questions - being ridiculed almost for just asking a basic question ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There are ways to get your point across without throwing insults at everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. PHP is a server side language which will have finished all it's processing long before your AJAX call is even fired.

What you need to do is have your `test.php` page which you submit the AJAX request to return the data you want back - be it a string, HTML, XML or JSON, and then use some jQuery code in your success handler to update the page.

For example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url:"test.php",
            success: function(result) {
                $("#myExample").text(result.foobar);
            }
        }) 
    }
</script> 

<span id="myExample"></span>
```